# numpy tofile puts single quotes in every line

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to save a string array in a file, using numpy.. Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np


items = ["Hello World"] * 5

np.array(items).tofile('hello.txt', "\n")
```

It works, but the problem is every line in the output has a single quote, which makes it look like this:

```
'Hello World'
'Hello World'
'Hello World'
'Hello World'
'Hello World'
```

How can I make numpy write the output like this? and with an extra line at the end?

```
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need numpy for this?

Comment: That perfectly valid question aside; why does numpy do this?

Comment: Although, thankfully, `items = ["Hello's World"] * 5` doesn't break it as it will enclose in double quotes. This is clearly intentional behaviour. I think the method is only meant to be used for reading/writing numpy objects and not what you're trying to do.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad

I want to do this very same thing with about 1000000000 lines ... file.write() is too slow

I am giving numpy a try, but it prints them like that, which I don't need them to look like

Comment: Numpy is not going to be faster for I/O than Python. Writing a billion lines will take time and probably should be handled in a custom way by defining buffers etc, not throwing to a generic method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve this by explicitly passing the (curiously default) format string:

```
np.array(items).tofile('test.txt', '\n', '%s')
```

Apparently the function signature in [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html) is, probably for illustration purposes, different from [the one actually used](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/8f37d88ebc0f265e451d7f5bca6d6ad885341a83/numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c#L563). The actual signature uses keyword arguments and hence is able to detect whether a format string was given or not. If missing they probably choose a suitable default depending on the data type (though I couldn't find the relevant code for that).

Comment: Err, wut? :P This seems such a strange configuration but it does work.

Comment: Thanks @a_guest ... For some reason, even when it was the default, it didn't work as expected ... Just weird

Comment: @roganjosh I have no idea why this works, especially since `'%s'` is the default for that argument. The only way this could work is an explicit check against `fmt is func.__defaults__[1]` but it's implemented at the C-level anyway I suppose.

Comment: @a_guest Even reading the caveats, I'm thinking this is either a bug or a mismatch of the documentation with the latest code?

Comment: @a_guest .. Do you happen to know the solution for adding an extra line at the end of the file?

Comment: @roganjosh Apparently the corresponding [C function](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/8f37d88ebc0f265e451d7f5bca6d6ad885341a83/numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c#L563) parses keyword arguments and hence can detect whether the format string was given or not. Not sure how the default is chosen though.

Comment: @JahirFiquitiva Just add an empty string to the end of the list, i.e. `np.array(items + [''])`.

Comment: @a_guest Great! Thank you so much

Comment: Using '%r' instead of the '%s' adds the quotes.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes but why would it be used? The docs say `'%s'` is the default.